# Type error: Invalid invocation

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive

`scope.width = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();`

Throws below error

> TypeError: 'get x' called on an object that does not implement interface DOMRect. error in firefox and Invalid invocation in chrome

Can someone explain me what is this?

Comment: What is `element` and what is `element[0]`?

Comment: element is searchable dropdown. below is the function added to scope            **app.directive("searchableMultiselect", function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        scope: {
            displayAttr: "@",   //one way binding & only expression
            selectedItems: "=", //two way binding & expects model name
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
           scope.width = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();

Comment: Please provide proper example of your code. `searchable dropdown` is too generic to tell what's wrong with `element[0]`. Edit your question and not post code to comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

is a method which is a part of the DOMRect interface. In order to use it, you have you call it on an element which implements the interface of DOMRect, I.E. Canvas.

The selected element you chose (DropDown in this case) does not implement the DOMRect interface, therefore is unable to use it's method `getBoundingClientRect`.

Therefore the error:

> ypeError: 'get x' called on an object that does not implement
>   interface DOMRect. error in firefox and Invalid invocation in chrome

You cannot use this method on dropdown, unless you modify the prototype whih is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the information. :)